# How to invoke CXF Asynchronous web service from apache camel

Tags: apache, xmpp, cxf, apache-camel, openfire

I have a javascript client which invokes an asynchronous web service with the callback in apache tomcat server. Webservice places the request to xmpp server and returns. I have another receiver component which receives the message from the xmpp server process it and puts back the response in another xmpp receiver queue. Now I would like to know of by connecting Apache Camel to the receiver queue, how can I notify the client callback. Do we have any option in apache camel to do this.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this.

thanks
Lokesh

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: no I have not tried, would like to know if it is possible